# read and write logs in sftp

Tags: sftp

I have to setup logs in sftp, I found out some link online and i made the following changes in sshd.conf

```
Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp -l info
```

and after that i restarted sshd services.

still there is no detailed entry for file upload and delete, only opne connections and close connection

```
Feb 13 14:12:31 ip-172-31-51-97 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of ubuntu.
Feb 13 14:12:31 ip-172-31-51-97 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Feb 13 14:12:31 ip-172-31-51-97 systemd[1]: Started Session 736 of user ubuntu.
```

Machine is an ubuntu 16 instance in Amazon

Comment: Where is the link you used to set this up.

Comment: I used same link  George, but it only shows session start log